# Node: 'binary_crossentropy/Cast' Cast string to float is not supported

Tags: python, deep-learning

Dears,
I am facing this error while training the model. I check the data and all of it is float dtype.

```
# import libraries needed 
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns  # data visualization library based on matplotlib

# loaded data file from google drive
df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Data/data.csv')

# change diagnosis to Label for better description
df = df.rename(columns={'diagnosis': 'Label'})
df.info()

# plot for better understanding 
sns.countplot(x='Label', data=df)

# Replace categorical value with number 
# - show what categorical are there  
category = df['Label'].value_counts()
print('Distribution of date \n', category)

# - define the categorical values that needs to be predicated (Label)
y = df['Label'].values
print('Labels before encoding are: \n', np.unique(y))

# Encoding categorical data from (B and M) to integers (0 and 1)
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
Y = labelencoder.fit_transform(y) # B=0 , M=1
print('Labels after encoder \n', np.unique(Y))

# define X and normalize/ scale values 
# - define the independ varibals. Drop Label and ID, and normalize other data 
X = df.drop(labels = ['Label', 'id', 'Unnamed: 32'], axis=1)
# print(X.describe().T) # needs scaling 

# scale/ normalize the values to bring them to similar range 
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(X)
X = scaler.transform(X)
print(X)

# split data into train and test to verify accuacy after fitting the model 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)
print('Shape of training data is: ', X_train.shape)
print('Shape of testing data is: ', X_test.shape)

# A Sequential model is appropriate for a plain stack of layers where each layer has exactly one input tensor and one output tensor
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(16, input_dim=30, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

# Fit with no early stopping or other callbacks
# - verbose=1 means to show output while training, verbose=0 means not to show output while training 
# - batch_size=64 means it loads 64 data points at one time and repeate with other 64 data points 
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, verbose=1, epochs=100, batch_size=64, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

Data info. when I print out the data.info, I got all data are integers. There is only one has object dtype and the Labels which i already encoded.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 569 entries, 0 to 568
Data columns (total 33 columns):
 #   Column                   Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------                   --------------  -----  
 0   id                       569 non-null    int64  
 1   Label                    569 non-null    object 
 2   radius_mean              569 non-null    float64
 3   texture_mean             569 non-null    float64
 4   perimeter_mean           569 non-null    float64
 5   area_mean                569 non-null    float64
 6   smoothness_mean          569 non-null    float64
 7   compactness_mean         569 non-null    float64
 8   concavity_mean           569 non-null    float64
 9   concave points_mean      569 non-null    float64
 10  symmetry_mean            569 non-null    float64
 11  fractal_dimension_mean   569 non-null    float64
 12  radius_se                569 non-null    float64
 13  texture_se               569 non-null    float64
 14  perimeter_se             569 non-null    float64
 15  area_se                  569 non-null    float64
 16  smoothness_se            569 non-null    float64
 17  compactness_se           569 non-null    float64
 18  concavity_se             569 non-null    float64
 19  concave points_se        569 non-null    float64
 20  symmetry_se              569 non-null    float64
 21  fractal_dimension_se     569 non-null    float64
 22  radius_worst             569 non-null    float64
 23  texture_worst            569 non-null    float64
 24  perimeter_worst          569 non-null    float64
 25  area_worst               569 non-null    float64
 26  smoothness_worst         569 non-null    float64
 27  compactness_worst        569 non-null    float64
 28  concavity_worst          569 non-null    float64
 29  concave points_worst     569 non-null    float64
 30  symmetry_worst           569 non-null    float64
 31  fractal_dimension_worst  569 non-null    float64
 32  Unnamed: 32              0 non-null      float64
dtypes: float64(31), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 146.8+ KB
```

Error: Node: 'binary_crossentropy/Cast'
Cast string to float is not supported

```
Epoch 1/100
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnimplementedError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-28c3db12122c> in <module>()
      2 # - verbose=1 means to show output while training, verbose=0 means not to show output while training
      3 # - batch_size=64 means it loads 64 data points at one time and repeate with other 64 data points
----> 4 history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, verbose=1, epochs=100, batch_size=64, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     53     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     54     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 55                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     56   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     57     if name is not None:

UnimplementedError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'binary_crossentropy/Cast' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 846, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 499, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 132, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 541, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1786, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py", line 88, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 122, in _handle_events
      handler_func(fileobj, events)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 577, in _handle_events
      self._handle_recv()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 606, in _handle_recv
      self._run_callback(callback, msg)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 556, in _run_callback
      callback(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
      return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
      handler(stream, idents, msg)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
      user_expressions, allow_stdin)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 208, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your issue is the following. You didnt fully encode all label columns, transformed into a float. That is what is causing the error this specific line right here.

```
Y = labelencoder.fit_transform(y)
```

As you can see, it only redefines your uppercased Y variable, not the y variable you are passing to your train_test_split function. So you can either, use your Y variable in the train_test_split. Or define it correctly

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)
```